# MySQL query Difference between previous and next row value in different columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
This is DistributorTransaction Table where
FullJarsOut = QuantityDelivered + Spoiled + FullJarsReturn

ID     FullJarsOut      QuantityDelivered      Spoiled         FullJarsReturn
P1     100              70                     10              20
P2     200              180                    5               15
P3     300              260                    13              27

where I want output from above table as

FullJarsOut        FullJarsReturn         Delivered (FullJarsOut – FullJarsReturn)
100                       0                      100
200                       20                     180
300                       15                     285
```

```
I want difference of 
200 from FullJarsOut column with 20 in FullJarsReturn(previous colums) as 200 - 20
300 from FullJarsOut column with 15 in FullJarsReturn(previous colums) as 300 - 15
from DistributorTransaction Table
```

Comment: Elaborate what you want to achieve. You created a post called "QUESTION" that is not a question.

Comment: In mySQL you will need a stored procedure that selects the table into a temp table that will allow you to compare row by row.

Comment: I have images but can't upload them because i have just started account and have reputations less than 10.

Comment: @user3176090: MySQL or SQL Server? or both !!!???

Comment: @Ravinder in mysql or Sql Sever

Comment: Um...MySQL and SQL Server both?  That's interesting... Anyhow, how are you going to determine the "previous" row?  In other words, how are you sorting it?

Comment: @Andrew Sorting data by ID

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server version**

```
WITH ordered_xactions as
  (
    select id, FullJarsOut, FullJarsReturn, Rank() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rank_id
     FROM DistributorTransaction
  )
SELECT 
  ox1.FullJarsOut FullJarsOut
  ,COALESCE(ox2.FullJarsReturn, 0) FullJarsReturn
  ,(ox1.FullJarsOut - COALESCE(ox2.FullJarsReturn, 0)) Delivered
FROM ordered_xactions ox1
LEFT JOIN ordered_xactions ox2
ON ox2.rank_id = ox1.rank_id - 1;
```

First, the data is ranked based on ID. Then, the FullJarsReturn value of a lower-ranked row is subtracted from FullJarsOut of the current row.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0bbc9/4)</kbd>

**MySQL version**

```
SELECT 
  d1.FullJarsOut
  ,d2.FullJarsReturn
  ,d1.FullJarsOut - d2.FullJarsReturn Delivered
FROM DistributorTransaction d1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT dt1.ID, COALESCE(MAX(dt2.ID), dt1.ID) max_id
 FROM DistributorTransaction dt1
 LEFT JOIN DistributorTransaction dt2
 ON dt2.ID < dt1.ID
 GROUP by dt1.ID
) max_ids
ON d1.ID = max_ids.ID
INNER JOIN DistributorTransaction d2
ON d2.ID = max_ids.max_id;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bbc9/10)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

@Joseph-b Thank you for answering the question. I used the mysql version and i have done some changes in query.

SELECT 
  d1.FullJarsOut
  ,COALESCE(d2.FullJarsReturn,0) FullJarsReturn
  ,COALESCE(d1.FullJarsOut - d2.FullJarsReturn,0) Delivered
FROM DistributorTransaction d1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT dt1.ID, COALESCE(MAX(dt2.ID), 0) max_id
 FROM DistributorTransaction dt1
 LEFT JOIN DistributorTransaction dt2
 ON dt2.ID < dt1.ID
 GROUP BY dt1.ID
) max_ids
ON d1.ID = max_ids.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DistributorTransaction d2
ON d2.ID = max_ids.max_id